# java regex not operator not working properly

Tags: java, regex

`(\d+(\.|\,|\\|\/|\-)\d+)` I have a regex like this. I'm catching numbers like 15.12, 15/15 with this regex it works correctly. But when I get the inverse with the not operator, it doesn't exactly work properly. Regex with "not" operator. `[^(\d+(\.|\,|\\|\/|\-)\d+)]`

Let's take **"15/12 tons/tonne"** as the sample text. Here I expect it to find **ton/ton**, but it doesn't take the **"/"** character, it just takes **tonton**. What am I doing wrong ? How can I fix ?

---

**Example;**

```
15/13 48 km/h  ---> 48 km/h

13.12 ton.     ---> ton.

10,11 ,kwh     ---> ,kwh

9-7 .mm.       ---> .mm.
```

As seen in the example, I want to find everything except numbers(including whitespaces).

Comment: Your character class is very explicitly *not* matching `/`

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here, or why you would expect `ton/ton`.  Are you saying you want to find slashes, dots, commas etc but only with non-numeric characters surrounding them?  And how should the space in the middle be interpreted?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're going after, but post on your bolded example:

^\d+/\d+\s+(tons/tonne)$

Comment: (\d+(\.|\,|\\|\/|\-)\d+) with this regex I can find 15/12 in 15/12 tone/ton sentence. I want to find the whitespace ton/tonne by inverting it. I don't want to find things like slash commas separately I want to find anything other than "number character number".@DawoodibnKareem

Comment: I want to find tone/ton in 15/12 tone/ton sentence. If the sentence was 15-12 abc-abc I would like to find abc-abc. I want to find anything other than "number character number".@Ryan

Comment: Your goal is extremely unclear.  You need to provide a bunch of examples showing what you want.  For instance, what output do you want given the input `abc 123`?  Now provide a few dozen matching and non-matching examples.

Comment: @JimGarrison added examples to the question. `abc 123` i took care of this situation.

Answer (score 1):

`[^(\d+(\.|\,|\\|\/|\-)\d+)]` is not the inverse of `(\d+(\.|\,|\\|\/|\-)\d+)`

In regular expressions, anything between the brackets are considered a character set.  The `^` is a special character when it's the first character in the set, with it meaning the inverse of the character set.

https://regex101.com/r/7gJANc/4

This is a good way to see exactly which characters are being matched (or not matched) by that pattern.

Last edit:

To find what you're looking for, you can invert each of the instances of `\d` to `\D`.  `\D` means "not-digit".

`(\D+(\.|\,|\\|\/|\-)\D+)` is your pattern but with `\D`:

https://regex101.com/r/7gJANc/5

It matches  `tons/tonne`

Comment: thanks for your answer. (\D+(\.|\,|\\|\/|\-)\D+) this expression won't work for "15/12 tons of tons" though. What should we do for this situation? I want it to work in both "15/12 tons of tons" and "15/12 tons/tons". actually i want everything except "number charceter number".

Comment: Here's a way `(?:\d+[.,\\\/-]\d+)?(.*)` , but depending on all of your use cases it may not work out.  This captures your number/number pattern if it exists.  Everything else is captured into group 1.

Comment: One note about that pattern, I modified `(\.|\,|\\|\/|\-)` from your pattern to be `[.,\\\/-]`.  It ends up describing the same thing.  The dot doesn't need the backslash within the character set to be interpreted as a literal dot, and the dash doesn't when it's not part of a range.

Comment: (?:\d+[.,\\\/-]\d+)?(.*) I guess I'll use that. I'm going to have to modify my code a bit but there doesn't seem to be any other solution. **but it may not work depending on all your use cases**. What situations could it be?

Comment: It depends on what all you're throwing at it.   What I remind myself when working with regular expressions is this quote by Jamie Zawinski:  "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."

Comment: I agree with Jamie Zawinski :) thanks for your answers.